# Auto fill text box depending on Drop Down value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-events

This might be a stupid question but I would like to have a clarification on how to go about this. I have come across quite a few articles that let to set the values of a text box depending on the choices made in a drop down menu using jQuery and Ajax. My issue is when I'm trying to do the same depending on the choices made in 5 drop down menus. I have the Id values stored in the database which should be used to populate the text box. Can anyone guide on how to go about this issue with multiple drop downs. This is my code so far:

```
    <?php
     $sql1="SELECT Schlungen  FROM schulung as s"; 
     $result=mysql_query($sql1); 
     echo "<p align='left'> <strong>Schulung 1</strong> <select name='Schlungen1'>           <option value default></option>";
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
     {
     echo "<option value='" . $row['Schlungen'] . "'>" . $row['Schlungen'] . "   </option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
      ?>

      <?php
      error_reporting(0);
      //Drop Down for Schulung 2
      $sql2="SELECT Schlungen  FROM schulung as s"; 
      $result=mysql_query($sql2); 
      echo "<p align='left'> <strong>Schulung 2</strong> <select name='Schlungen2'>  <option value default></option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Schlungen'] . "'>" . $row['Schlungen'] . " </option>";
       }
      echo "</select>";
      ?>


      <?php
      error_reporting(0);
      //Drop Down for Schulung 3 
      $sql3="SELECT Schlungen  FROM schulung as s"; 
      $result=mysql_query($sql3); 
      echo "<p align='left'> <strong>Schulung 3</strong> <select name='Schlungen3'> <option value default></option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Schlungen'] . "'>" . $row['Schlungen'] . "</option>";
       }
      echo "</select>";
      ?>

      <?php
      error_reporting(0);
      //Drop Down for Schulung 4 
      $sql4="SELECT Schlungen  FROM schulung as s"; 
      $result=mysql_query($sql4); 
      echo "<p align='left'> <strong>Schulung 4</strong> <select name='Schlungen4'><option value default></option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Schlungen'] . "'>" . $row['Schlungen'] . " </option>";
       }
      echo "</select>";
      ?>

      <?php
      error_reporting(0);
      //Drop Down for Schulung 5  
      $sql5="SELECT Schlungen  FROM schulung as s"; 
      $result=mysql_query($sql5); 
      echo "<p align='left'> <strong>Schulung 5</strong> <select name='Schlungen5'><option value default></option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Schlungen'] . "'>" . $row['Schlungen'] . " </option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
      ?>   
      <p align="left"><strong>Access_level </strong> 
      <input type="text" name="a_level" disabled="disabled">
      </p>
```

Comment: can you show me how the output appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving auto completion,you can create a select field in html file,call a javascript function on keyup event and use jQuery for calling your php file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        $('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){
         $.post("<your file.php>",{any data you need},function(data){
          //echo the data
        //echo "<option value='" . $row['Schlungen'] . "'>" . //$row['Schlungen'] ."   </option>";
        $('.result').html(data)

});
        });
        $('.result option').click(function(){
            var rValue = $(this).text();
            $('.autosuggest').attr('value',rValue);        
            $('.result').html('');
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='text' class='autosuggest'/>
    <select class='result'>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the value of each html select option to be the id of that text

so the echo should be

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['Schlungen'] . " </option>";
```

then on the html select add the event **onchange** and add the JS function foo() to fill a hidden input with all selected ids by getting them from the page using the JQuery or Javascript

also you have to add id or class for each html select to get its selected value easily

```
$("#select1").val();
$("#select2").val(); ...
```

then insert these values in a hidden  input field so the hidden input  now contains all selected ids