# Auto results search form jquery

Tags: jquery, search

I would like to have a search form (with more than one field) that would display the avaible results as the person types the value, geting these values from my database.

Doing some research I found the code below, but as you can see it works with words pre-defined by hand, and not using a database to recover values like I want.

Is there a way I can change this code, maybe the script, to achieve the result I want?

```
<head>
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: are you using php or something else ?

Comment: if you are trying to achieve autocompletion you can try
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13346080/1440342

Comment: @rahul yes the search form's file is in php

Comment: @mah2602 see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

you can see these two links

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

if you are using `php`

http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-a-remote-database-and-php/

http://burnmind.com/howto/how-to-feed-jquery-uis-autocomplete-with-a-database-generated-dataset

if you are using `asp.net`

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-AutoComplete-Plugin-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: My search field looks like this `<div class="search_col2">
      <?php



 echo $field->loadsearchfield($fields[$i]->id, 0, array('form'=>'searchform'));



?>
    </div>` but on the tutorial I must put an ID "auto" inside the input box, is there a way I can specify this inside the PHP file? Thank you.

Comment: I did this with this link http://burnmind.com/howto/how-to-feed-jquery-uis-autocomplete-with-a-database-generated-dataset

Used the generated ID on the html on the fields I wanted. Worked perfectly.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use remote data source

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: "specify_url_to_your_server_here"
    })
```

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

And of course you need some server-side to support this.

Comment: I'm a begginer with php and javascript, so would you please help me finding a source where I can see how exactly I should confiure my server-side? Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not a php guy. :) Check links provided by @rahul.