# jQuery, Ajax fill drop down list

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call with a working function to fill a drop down list but I would like the function to receive variables to fill a drop down list instead of specific to the url which is uses to pull the data

I have

```
var string = '';
success: function (item)
if (item != '') {
  for (var x = 0; x < item.food.length; x++) {
    var filler = '<option value=' + item.food[i].name + '">' + item.food[i].name + '</option>';
    string += filler;
  }
  $("#food-list").html(string);
}
});
```

Comment: And what is the issue here? Also why are you not doing a string += filler?

Comment: The issue is to make this more generalized. For example how to set a variable = to item.food.length, item.food[i].name and #food-list) so that they can be used with various urls

Comment: you may want to take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344814/auto-fill-text-box-depending-on-drop-down-value/13346080#13346080

Comment: how would you change item.food.length to be more generic such as containing a general word instead of food or can you set the whole string to a variable

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me but that only mistake, "I think" is the variable inside the array of food it might be `x` instead of `i`.

```
var food =['Sandwish', 'Hamburguer', 'Tacos']
var string = '';

success: function (item){
  if (food) {
    for (var x = 0; x < item.food.length; x++) {
     var filler = '<option value=' + item.food[x].name + '">' + item.food[x].name + '</option>';
     string +=filler;
     }
   $("#food-list").html(string);
 }
}
});
```

Here is a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/r2q37/) with an example, hope it helps you.