# auto generate text box with database values when drop down list selected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two interdependent drop drown, 2nd drop down value populates when 1st drop down value selected, When i select 2nd drop down it has to populate text boxes with the values stored in database.

My drop down list is working but i am not getting how to populate text boxes when 2nd drop down selected.

Here is my code

jquery

```
<script>

    function showItems(sel) {
        var cat_id = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
        $("#output1").html( "" );

        if (cat_id.length > 0 ) {

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "fetch_items.php",
                data: "cat_id="+cat_id,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#output1').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                },
                success: function(html) {    
                    $("#output1").html( html );
                }
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Form(dropdown)

```
<div class="formSep">

<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM item_category";
$query2 = mysql_query($sql2);
?>

<select name="category" onChange="showItems(this);">
  <option value="">Item Category</option>
<?php while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $rs2["item_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs2["name"]?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>




 <div id="output1"></div>
```

fetch_items.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include("../connect.php");
include("../admin_auth.php"); 

$cat_id = ($_REQUEST["cat_id"] <> "") ? trim( addslashes($_REQUEST["cat_id"])) : "";
if ($cat_id <> "" ) { 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items where category=".$cat_id."";
$count = mysql_num_rows( mysql_query($sql) );
if ($count > 0 ) {
$query = mysql_query($sql);
?>

<select name="items">
    <option value="">Items</option>
    <?php while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rs["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

in textboxes i should get values from items table, for that query

```
$m1 = "select * from order_line_items where order_id=".$order_id."";
                   $result = mysqli->query($m1);

                   $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Please suggest me how to generate text boxes.

Comment: Any error message? Check your ajax-request-result using the developer tools (F12 -> go to 'Network' -> select your query and -> open the response tab)

Comment: No i am not getting the logic itself. I Need some suggestions... may be any tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344814/auto-fill-text-box-depending-on-drop-down-value?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Yeah but for example you already send the AJAX-Request. What do you get back? Where EXACTLY are you stuck?! e.g. What does the response look like?
Btw: you should use the object notation for Jquery's data-element in the AJAX Request. Something like `data: { cat_id: cat_id }`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a poor attempt to help you, and I've made a huge number of assumptions.

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jgad5dq4/2/) is operational with the general concepts you mentioned.

I've assumed that the first option list is populated for php code on the same page.

The second option list is generated after a selection from the first list, and then an AJAX call to a db (hypothetical).

Then after selecting from the second list, another ajax call is made that returns a json data. That data is parsed and distributed.

Perhaps this will give you a start.

A LOT of JS

```
var vartopass;

$('.option1').append("<option id='africa'>Africa</option><option id='india'>India</option><option id='namerica'>North America<option>");

$('.option1').on('change', function(){

    if( $(".option1 #africa").prop('selected') === true )
       {
       $('.option2').append("<option id='elephant'>Elephant</option><option id='rhinoceros'>Rhinoceros</option><option id='giraffe'>Giraffe</option>");
       $('.option2').css('visibility', 'visible');
       }

    if( $(".option1 #india").prop('selected') === true )
      {
       $('.option2').append("<option id='tiger'>Tiger</option><option id='waterbuffalo'>Water Buffalo</option><option id='snowleopard'>Snowleopard</option>");
       $('.option2').css('visibility', 'visible');
       }

    if( $(".option1 #namerica").prop('selected') === true )
      {
       $('.option2').append("<option id='deer'>Mule Deer</option><option id='elk'>Elk</option><option id='moose'>Moose</option>");
       $('.option2').css('visibility', 'visible');
       }        
});

$('.option2').on('change', function(){
    vartopass = $('.option2').children(":selected").attr("id");
    console.log( vartopass );
/*
This is a hypothetical data return from an ajax call that takes the data from your option list, passes it to a php file, the server returns JSON data, and it is parsed and loaded into divs.

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gogetthestuff.php",
            data: {animal: vartopass}
            .done(function(data){
                    $('.putmehere1').val(result.height);
                    $('.putmehere1').val(result.weight);
                                 });
        });
*/



//Hypothetical callback from JSON array returned by AJAX:
var animals = [
    {
    "elephant": {
        "height": "126",
        "weight": "6000"
    },
    "rhinocerus": {
        "height": "88",
        "weight": "4000"
    },
    "giraffe": {
        "height": "400",
        "weight": "2000"
    },
    "tiger": {
        "height": "44",
        "weight": "1000"
    },
    "waterbuffalo": {
        "height": "128",
        "weight": "5000"
    },
    "snowleopard": {
        "height": "38",
        "weight": "600"
    },
    "deer": {
        "height": "98",
        "weight": "180"
    },
    "elk": {
        "height": "188",
        "weight": "2000"
    },
    "moose": {
        "height": "288",
        "weight": "5000"
    }
}
];

$('.putmehere1').html( "<br />Animal height: " + 
                        eval( 'animals[0].' + vartopass + '.height' ) + 
                        " inches" );
$('.putmehere2').html( "<br />Animal weight: " + 
                        eval( 'animals[0].' + vartopass + '.weight' ) + 
                        ' pounds' );

});
```

Comment: I resolved this one. I have created one more file to fetch item details. Thanks a lot